# Is there any way to save the current state of kubernetes pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a pod running linux, i have installed many software/tools, if I restart the pod, k8s will start a new pod and I'll lose all my resources installed, is there any way to save the pod as docker image or any other way it can be persistant even after restarting pod.

[Is there a way to download the container image from a pod in kuberentes environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481849/is-there-a-way-to-download-the-container-image-from-a-pod-in-kuberentes-environm) tried the solution, but wasn't helpful.

Comment: Pods by design are ephemeral and don't keep state after being restarted.  you can add a shell script to run every time a pod is started and install what you want.

Comment: I don't see why you would want to download an image from a pod, the images are available from some registry but if you want to download files from a pod, you can use ```kubectl cp```

Comment: volumes are meant to capture state.

Comment: As a general rule, you should never install software in a running container or pod; you _will_ lose work when the container exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the link is not wrong, you will probably have to jump through some hoops. One method I can think of is to:

1. Run a container that has the docker cli installed, mounts the docker socket from the host, and has an node affinity rule so that the container is scheduled on the same node as the container you want to capture.
2. From within this container, you should be able to access the docker daemon running on the node, issue docker commands to capture, tag, push the updated image.

I wouldn't advise doing this though... have not tested it myself but I have done something "similar" before.

It would be better to create your own dockerfile, install software, and use that image for your containers.